How to get type of expression/value/column?
In PostgreSQL I can find the type of the expression using pg_typeof:
select pg_typeof(5);




pg_typeof




integer



What is the SurrealDB's alternative of that?
I found that I can check that the value has the specific type via the set of functions type::is::*, but it's not exactly what I want

this is currently not possible, but there is an open feature request for the same function: https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/issues/4412
Feel free to contribute to the above issue!
